# How can I convert keys in a hash from strings to symbols?

Tags: json, ruby, hash, key

I am new to Ruby. I'm  trying to import a file and use it as a variable in  a certain format.

JSON file snippet (data.json):

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "vehicle": "car",
    "options": {
      "doors": "4",
      "make": "Nissan"
      "model": "Altima"
      "year": "2020"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "vehicle": "car",
    "options": {
      "doors": "4",
      "make": "Nissan"
      "model": "Maxima"
      "year": "2020"
    }
  }]
```

I am trying to import that JSON in a format that looks like this:

```
[{:id=>1, :vehicle=>"car", :options=>{:doors=>"4", :make=>"Nissan", :model=>"Altima", :"year": "2020"}}, {:id=>2, :vehicle=>"car", :options=>{:doors=>"4", :make=>"Nissan", :model=>"Maxima", :"year": "2020"}}]
```

I want to change the keys to symbols. So instead of `"id"=>1` I want `:id=>1`. I am having problems converting the options hashes because they are nested.

Currently I have:

```
data = File.read("data.json")
```

but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

### Fix Your  Data First

First, fix your JSON data. As originally posted, your sample input is *not* valid JSON because it's missing commas between the options. Corrected output would be as follows:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "vehicle": "car",
    "options": {
      "doors": "4",
      "make": "Nissan",
      "model": "Altima",
      "year": "2020"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "vehicle": "car",
    "options": {
      "doors": "4",
      "make": "Nissan",
      "model": "Maxima",
      "year": "2020"
    }
  }]
```

### Transforming Keys from Strings to Symbols

#### Parse File as JSON

Once you've fixed your input data, you can parse the data from your file using [Kernel#open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-open) and [JSON#load](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load). For example:

```rb
require "json"
vehicles = JSON.load open("data.json")
```

#### Transform Keys

Next, you'll need to transform your keys using [Hash#transform_keys!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21) and [String#to_sym](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-to_sym). For example:

```rb
vehicles.map do |hash|
  # convert top-level keys from String to Symbol
  hash.transform_keys! { |key| key.to_sym }

  # convert top-level keys in options hash
  hash[:options].transform_keys! { |key| key.to_sym }
end
```

Pretty-printing *vehicles* will now yield the following:

```rb
pp vehicles

[{:id=>1,
  :vehicle=>"car",
  :options=>{:doors=>"4", :make=>"Nissan", :model=>"Altima", :year=>"2020"}},
 {:id=>2,
  :vehicle=>"car",
  :options=>{:doors=>"4", :make=>"Nissan", :model=>"Maxima", :year=>"2020"}}]
```

### Caveats

This solution handles any number of keys at the top level of each hash, and any number of top-level keys in each options hash, but doesn't handle any nesting beyond that. If you have irregular JSON objects with arbitrary levels of nested hashes, you might need to walk the hash to whatever depth you need through other means.

Comment: is there a way to have it be formatted like 

[{:id=>1, :vehicle=>"car", :options=>{:doors=>"4", :make=>"Nissan", :model=>"Altima", :"year": "2020"}}, {:id=>2, :vehicle=>"car", :options=>{:doors=>"4", :make=>"Nissan", :model=>"Maxima", :"year": "2020"}}]

Comment: @user13666088 See the return value posted above. It's already doing that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't really explain the question too well. But it's more about changing the keys  to symbols. So instead of "id"=>1 you get :id=>1. I am having problems converting that in options because they are nested.

Answer (score 0):

`File.read` only reads the file to a string but doesn't parse the content as json.

```
require 'json'
file = File.read('data.json')
data = JSON.parse(file)
```